# Angular 15 SSR and Lazy-Loading module not loading state on server

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

Recently we started changing our architecture from Angular SSR to use SSR with Lazy Loading modules.

In the first versions the modules were all imported on our `routes` file.

A component, for instance, would load data from our API and if running at the server would add data to the `transferState`. At the browser, we would check if the state existed, if not, load from the backend.

Now our components are lazy-loaded in different modules:

- `App Module` lazy-loads `A module` with `A component`
- `A Module` lazy-loads `B module` with `B component`

before `B component` would load data as stated before (with `transferState`), but the behavior now is to load only on the client side.

Did we get it wrong that it would be possible to continue using server-side loading, or something was implemented wrongly?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Repository for reproduction: https://github.com/guiligan/repro-app-3061/

Comment: I think you're right, that your assumption that it would continue to use SSR is wrong. The `TransferState` only transfers state on the first load, after that your application runs in client-side mode, thus all requests happen from the client to a backend API.

Comment: @ChrisGilardi it used to work with SSR before using lazy-load